# Pubsub avro schema testing: "Message is invalid against schema"

Tags: nested, schema, avro, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to create a schema in pubsub which I plan to use when I create my topic.
My avro schema is nested and it looks likes this:

```
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "topLevelRecord",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "dT_AssignmentExt",
    "type" : [ {
      "type" : "array",
      "items" : [ {
        "type" : "record",
        "name" : "dT_AssignmentExt",
        "namespace" : "topLevelRecord",
        "fields" : [ {
          "name" : "arrivalStation",
          "type" : [ "string", "null" ]
        }, {
          "name" : "arrivalTime",
          "type" : [ "string", "null" ]
        } ]
      }, "null" ]
    }, "null" ]
  }, {
    "name" : "dT_PlanHeaderExt",
    "type" : [ {
      "type" : "record",
      "name" : "dT_PlanHeaderExt",
      "namespace" : "topLevelRecord",
      "fields" : [ {
        "name" : "created",
        "type" : [ "string", "null" ]
      }, {
        "name" : "endDate",
        "type" : [ "string", "null" ]
      }, {
        "name" : "startDate",
        "type" : [ "string", "null" ]
      } ]
    }, "null" ]
  }, {
    "name" : "dT_RotationHeaderExt",
    "type" : [ {
      "type" : "record",
      "name" : "dT_RotationHeaderExt",
      "namespace" : "topLevelRecord",
      "fields" : [ {
        "name" : "locomotiveId",
        "type" : [ "string", "null" ]
      }, {
        "name" : "locomotiveType",
        "type" : [ "string", "null" ]
      } ]
    }, "null" ]
  } ]
}
```

It passes the validation but when I try to test a message it fails: `Message is invalid against schema.`
The message I try to test is following:

```
 "dT_AssignmentExt": [
    {
       "arrivalStation": "DE.AM",
       "arrivalTime": "2023-03-01T10:33:00Z"
    },
    {
       "arrivalStation": "DE.AM",
       "arrivalTime": "2023-03-13T15:00:00Z"
    }, 
    {
       "arrivalStation": "PHM",
       "arrivalTime": "2023-03-14T00:51:00Z"
    }, 
    {
       "arrivalStation": "MGB",
       "arrivalTime": "2023-03-14T01:17:00Z"
    }
 ],
 "dT_PlanHeaderExt": 
 {
    "created": "2023-03-01T11:32:00Z",
    "endDate": "2023-03-15T11:32:00Z",
    "startDate": "2023-03-01T11:32:00Z"
 },
 "dT_RotationHeaderExt": 
 {
    "locomotiveId": "5405",
    "locomotiveType": "BR185"
 }
}

{
  "dT_PlanHeaderExt": 
     {
        "created": "2023-03-01T11:32:00Z",
        "endDate": "2023-03-15T11:32:00Z",
        "startDate": "2023-03-01T11:32:00Z"
     }
}
```

Is pubsub able to handle nested avro or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The message does not specify the values for the union fields correctly. See the [Avro specification](https://www.grubhub.com/restaurant/insomnia-cookies-10669-braddock-rd-fairfax/3365835).

For example, `locomotiveId` needs to be specified as:

```
"locomotiveId": {
  "string": "5405"
}
```