# GCP Pub/Sub message validation against nested record AVRO schema fails

Tags: avro, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a fairly complex AVRO schema which passes the validation, but the message that's sent to it somehow isn't compatible with the AVRO schema I defined.

Since then, I tried narrowing down the schema to understand why this could be happening, and it seems that **nested record AVRO schema** doesn't work too well in Pub/Sub.

For example, consider the following AVRO schema:

```
{
 "type" : "record",
 "name" : "Avro",
 "fields" : [
   {
     "name" : "foo",
     "type" : {
        "name": "foo_1",
        "type": "int"
     }
   }
 ]
}
```

and the sample message:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "foo_1": 42
  }
}
```

The sample schema above passes the schema validation in Pub/Sub, but when I test the message above, it fails.

I found similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75812459/pubsub-avro-schema-testing-message-is-invalid-against-schema), but it doesn't really help much.

Perhaps, Pub/Sub has issue with nested record?

Thanks a bunch.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Kamal, the original message works. How would I handle UNION[NULL, nestedRecord] case? i.e.

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "Avro",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "foo",
            "type": [
              "null",
                {
                  "type": "record",
                  "name": "NestedRecord",
                  "fields": [
                      {
                          "name": "foo_1",
                          "type": "int"
                      }
                  ]
              }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Is this not a valid schema? My expectation is that this schema should handle both

```
{"foo": null}
```

and

```
{
  "foo": {
    "foo_1": 42
  }
}
```

but it only works for the `null` input, not with the nested input. Seems like a very basic question, but it's been very frustrating for me since Pub/Sub validation error isn't really useful..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The schema you have provided does not specify a nested record. Note that you have no additional `"record"` type inside the fields. The schema you want to match the message you have specified is:

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "Avro",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "foo",
            "type": {
                "type": "record",
                "name": "NestedRecord",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "name": "foo_1",
                        "type": "int"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The schema you specified has a record with a single `int` field with the name `foo`. The nested `"name"` specification is essentially ignored. This is a message that is valid against the schema you provided:

```
{
  "foo": 42
}
```

For the case of a `union` with `null`, you need to follow the [JSON encoding rules for a union](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.11.1/specification/#json-encoding). In this case, the message would be:

```
{
    "foo": {
        "NestedRecord": {
            "foo_1": 42
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh,, thanks. I guess the fact that the schema was valid threw me off..

Comment: Could you be able to take a look at the updated post please? I think the part that threw me off is the UNION with NULL.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Avro JSON format, for a non-null union you must include a type hint in the JSON data. More details here: https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/specification/#json-encoding

What that means is that instead of:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "foo_1": 42
  }
}
```

You probably need

```
{
  "foo": {
    "NestedRecord": {
      "foo_1": 42
    }
  }
}
```